# Steepest Descent Approximation applied to Integral Form

Tags: integration, asymptotics, indefinite-integrals, approximation, laplace-method

> To do an exponential integral of the form $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq ~e^{-(1/\hbar)f(q)}$ we often have to resort to the steepest descent approximation. In the limit of $\hbar$ small, the integral is dominated by the minimum of $f(q)$. Expanding $f(q) = f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(q-a)^2+O[(q-a)^3]$ and using
>
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx~ e^{-\frac{1}{2}{\rm a}x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\rm a}},\tag{17}$$
>
> we obtain
>
> $$ I = e^{-(1/\hbar) f(a)}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi\hbar}{f''(a)}}e^{-O(\hbar^{\frac{1}{2}})}. \tag{27}$$

When $\hbar$ is small we get $(1/\hbar)$ goes to infinity so I don't see how this is dominated by $f(a)$?

Comment: The quote is apparently footnote 38 on p. 61 in Ivancevic & Ivancevic: _New Trends in Control Theory._ The original quote contains several typos: An imaginary unit $i$ in the beginning disappears and a square root is missing in the final formula.

Comment: No this comes from an appendix in zee's qft in a nutshell

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which page?

Comment: page 16.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Rather than studying the complex [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent), I recommend to first study the real [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).
2. Perform a [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) $q=\sqrt{\hbar}x+a$ with $x$ as new integration variable.

References:

1. A. Zee. *QFT in a nutshell,* 2nd ed., 2010; p.16.